# Are there metalanguages that are used to describe source-code properties to enforce coding guidelines?

Tags: syntax, coding-style

Today there are a lot of different guidelines and standards (internal and external) for coding. There are also some tools that enforce that coding guidelines.

**I wonder if there are any languages helping to formulate coding guidelines that tools could make use of?**

I imagine they should be language-specific and be based on other metalanguages such as [Backus–Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). So that the rule "goto statement not allowed" could be described as:

```
rule_goto_statement_not_allowed ::= statement_delimiter + "goto" + 
                                    statement_delimiter + label + ";"

rule_goto_statement_not_allowed_error_message ::= line + "goto not allowed!"
```

Answer (score 1):

PMD has a rule language based on an AST for this purpose.

Comment: That's a nice example! I will look into it.